# Obout calendar and .css interupption

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, obout

my Obout calendar working fine but there seems to be a problem as the month scroller is not visible, after some trial and error i have found the cause of the problem to be one line in my asp css styling in the `head` however i cannot remove that line as it will cause problems with the rest of my website.

here is the line that is cause in the problem `table-layout: fixed;`
it is located in the head:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #form1
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
    td { overflow: hidden; }
    table { padding: 0px;
        table-layout: fixed;
        font-size: small;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-right: 0px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .style54
    {
        width: 1158px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    .style73
    {
        width: 99%;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
```

...............

here is my Obout calendar :

```
 <table border = "1"  ><tr> <td> Date :
 <ASP:TextBox runat="server" id="txtDate" />
 <obout:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server"
 CultureName="en-GB" 
 DatePickerMode = "true" 
 TextBoxId = "txtDate"
 Align="Under" DatePickerImagePath = "images/icon2.gif" >
</obout:Calendar> 
</td></tr></table>
```

how can i use my calender without the `table-layout: fixed;` line interfering?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to override table-layout:fixed in the Obout CSS?

Comment: @Jonatan Anctil im not sure how to do that mate, can you explain please

Comment: I don't remember if Obout controls comes with CSS files. If you can edit those files, find the class name define for calendar and set  table-layout:initial. If you can't modify CSS, Obout Calendar has a property CSSCalendar and i'm sure you can define a class name with table-layout property.

Comment: it says that  table-layout:initial, initial isnt a variable of table layout

Comment: i have tried the following: `<table style="table-layout: initial">` i have also tried to put a new item in the css called `table.test` with the `table-layout: initial`, i have also tried to put the `table-layout: initial` inside the calendars style `.css` file. but when i remove the `table-layout: fixed` from the internal css of the page it works fine but the rest of my tables get messed up :(

Comment: Have you try to use !important flag? `table-layout:initial !important`